# 'Column' CSS for earlier browsers

Tags: html, css

Can I imitate the CSS `column` property in earlier browsers without using Javascript?

I am trying to do something like:

```
A        E        I
B        F        J
C        G
D        H
```

I want to know if it is possible with only one element?

```html
<div class="columns">
    A<br/>
    B<br/>
    C<br/>
    D<br/>
    E<br/>
    F<br/>
    G<br/>
    H<br/>
    I<br/>
    J<br/>
</div>
```

Comment: When you say "_earlier browsers_", could you clarify how early you mean?  Also, are you limited to a single `<div>` containing elements with `<br />` between them or can the HTML be modified?

Comment: [`columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) are still supported in current browsers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way that could work is dividing up the letters like this:

```
<div class="col1"> 
    A
    B
    C
    D
</div>
<div class="col2">
    E
    F
    G
    H
</div>
<div class="col3">
    I
    J
</div>
```

And then the CSS looks like this:

```
.col1{
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    padding: 1em;
.col2{
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    padding: 1em;
.col3{
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    padding: 1em;
```

Comment: i was trying to not divide the div ito smaller divs because its tiresom for many columns but thanks anyway